# Can't display the chart using vistime

Tags: r, ubuntu, vistime

I have run the sample program from the following site using the vistime package in R. The browser starts, but the resulting chart is not displayed.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vistime/vignettes/vistime-vignette.html

The execution environment is Ubuntu installed using WSL2 on Windows 10, and R is running on Ubuntu.

I did the same thing using my Mac,　the browser started up and displayed.